# Win 8.1 DPI - WPF - How to find independent monitor/display's DPI

Tags: c#, wpf, dpi, windows-8.1

I have a Win 8.1 system installed on my system. I used to calculate `DPI` based on following in my WPF App (Win 7):

```
Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

double dx = m.M11;
double dy = m.M22;
```

With Win 8.1, I have the flexibility to have different DPI's set for different monitors. If I need to find out what are the DPI's of each monitor using WPF, how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read [Developing a Per-Monitor DPI-Aware WPF Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee308410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. This article covers pretty most of what you'll need to support High-DPI WPF Windows 8.1 apps.

Note, though, that the examples given in the article above are mostly written in C++, but that's less of an issue for WinRT apps since C++ and C# can now interop more easily than before.